# Does the MS Graph handle caching with ETag header?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to cache retrieved photo with given `ETag` from ms-graph. Here you have a command:

```
http 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user-mail]/photo/$value' Authorization:"Bearer [token]" If-None-Match:[prev_ETag] -v
```

Unfortunately instead of `304 Not Modified` I see `200 OK` response with binary data. Is there somehow a way to use ETag token to prevent refetching already downloaded photo? My aim is to decrease load of ms-graph. Is there any microsoft guide how to cache data from their API? I've tried to use `HEAD` http request but it isn't supported.

Comment: Something I've noticed is if you use F12 dev tools in a browser to debug network traffic it may show 200 and the cached payload even though the server has returned 304 and no body. Caught me out before trying to work out why ETag wasn't working but turns out it was and the browser was hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can cache the photo based on ETag. When you get the photo, you should get an `etag` response header. You can check if the photo has changed by getting the photo's metadata (instead of the photo itself):

```
GET /users/[user-mail]/photo
```

That will return some information about the current photo, including the ETag in the `@odata.mediaEtag` property.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('e6c10dc8-5218-46f7-a0c1-59026b45b0fe')/photo/$entity",
  "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
  "@odata.mediaEtag": "\"6A0C23F3\"",
  "id": "240X240",
  "height": 240,
  "width": 240
}
```

Comment: It seems like a workaround solution but not standard one